# Binary tree using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code from a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1499749007), it is an implementation of a preorder traversal of a binary tree:

```
template<typename tVal>
struct binaryTree
{
    tVal v__;
    struct binaryTree<tVal> *left;
    struct binaryTree<tVal> *right;

    binaryTree(tVal v) : v__(v),
        left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

template<typename tVal>
void nonRecursivePreOrder(binaryTree<tVal> * root)
{
    std::stack<binaryTree<tVal> *> s;

    while (true)
    {

        while (root)
        {
            std::cout << " v=" << root->v__;
            s.push(root);
            root = root->left;
        }
        if (s.empty()) break;

        root = s.top();
        s.pop();
        root = root->right;
    }
}
```

1. In the ternary operator in line 9, what does `{}` at the end do?
2. How can I implement an `insert` and `main` function that utilises the functions above?

edit: i've been informed line 9 is not a ternary operator but a "constructor initialization list"

Comment: I see no ternary operator there ... just standard constructor initialization list ... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: 1. there is no ternary operator 2. Just do it. If you need help you should show your attempt and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I don't think you're going to want to change your root during a traversal... :)

Comment: @erip `root` is just the function parameter

Comment: @tobi303 I commented a little too hastily. :) I'm used to seeing trees implemented a little differently where the tree class manages the root, which is a node. Should've looked a little closer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line 9 is just a constructor.

Something like that will do for you:

```
template<typename T>
void put(binaryTree<T>* root, T val) {
    binaryTree<T>* node = new binaryTree<int>(val);

    if (root == nullptr) {        
        root = node;
        return;
    }

    binaryTree<T>* cur = root;
    binaryTree<T>* parent = nullptr;
    while(cur) {
        parent = cur;
        cur = (node->v__ > cur->v__) ? cur->right 
                                     : cur->left;
    }

    (node->v__ < parent->v__) ? parent->left  = node 
                              : parent->right = node; 
} 


int main() {
    binaryTree<int>* b = new binaryTree<int>(10);
    put<int>(b, 11); 
    put<int>(b, 5);
    put<int>(b, 14);
    put<int>(b, 25);
    put<int>(b, 1);

    nonRecursivePreOrder<int>(b);

    return 0;
}
```